# My glasses seem to be polarizing the light when they want. What is happening?

Tags: visible-light, polarization

When I put the glasses on and I look at my computer monitor and I turn in a certain angle everything becomes black. When I do it on my laptop screen though I need a different angle. Finally when I look at other stuff (not the light emitting screens) nothing changes no matter the angle I turn. Although I know the basic physics of polarization I don't understand why light is not polarized when I look at other stuff than my screens.

Comment: LCD screens have polarizing filters built into them, the rest of your "stuff" doesn't.

Comment: Light from the blue sky is polarized, however depending on the angle and time of day.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're wearing polarizing sunglasses here?

Comment: Hi. I am not sure, if I turn at a certain angle light is completely blocked so there must be some polarizer in the glasses but they were not advertised us such.

Answer (score -1):

There are two general classes of polarization. Plane polarization where the electric field
is in a plane.  Glare reducing sun glasses use plane polarizers because reflections of water and other smooth surfaces are polarized due to Fresnel's laws of reflection.  The second type of polarization is circular or more generally elliptical polarization. The plane of polarization cork screws in two modes either left handed or right handed.  Stereoscopic movies now usually use this type of polarization so that head tilt won't affect viewing.

Comment: Don't think this really addresses the question.